# Passing an array into a var function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var reguser = function(btn,url,form_data,op) {
    $(btn).click(function(){
        postLoad(url,form_data,op);
        return false;
    });
}

var postLoad = function(url,form_data,op,fade) {
    $.post(base_url(url),form_data,function(q){$(op).html(q);});
}

var getVal = function(link) {
    return $(link).val();
};

var base_url = function(link) {
    return 'http://localhost/cw/' + link;
}
```

I have three var function here. I find it odd that when I want to pass on an array variable it doesn't get passed in my AJAX.

Here is how I execute the code (This has been declared in the $(document).ready();). The code above is stored in a separate file.

```
reguser('#add-acct','ctrl_register/AJAXreguser',{call:1,fname:getVal('#fname')},'#acct-detail');
```

The result:

> Array ( [call] => 1 [fname] => )

form code

```
    <form action="http://localhost/cw/ctrl_register" class="form-vertical" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="" class="span8 input-small"id="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <label for="mname">Middle Name</label>
<input type="text" name="mname" value="" class="span8 input-small"id="mname" placeholder="Middle Name" />
<label for="lname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" value="" class="span8 input-small"id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
<label for="user">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="user" value="" class="span8 input-small"id="user" placeholder="Username" />
<label for="pass">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="pass" value="" class="span8 input-small"id="pass" placeholder="Password" />
<label for="pass2">Confirm Password</label>
<input type="password" name="pass2" value="" class="span8 input-small"id="pass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
</br><input type="submit" name="Add-acct" value="Add Account" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-acct" />
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you get by `getVal('#fname')`?

Comment: @xdazz nothing. See the last part of the post.

Comment: @Gavriel from an form input. Assume that there's a text in it. The id is #fname.

Comment: #frame's value is "empty" as you can see above. Certeanly not an array, not even an empty array

Comment: @Gavriel I added a picture for reference. Hope this helps. See that even if I fill the first name (#fname) it doesn't get passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/flocsy/WC336/1/

The problem was that in reguser you want to register the onclick for the button you pass, but at the same call you pass the fname.val() which is empty 'cause you haven't yet filled it in.

The solution is to remove the onclick from register and have it in document.ready:

```
var reguser = function(btn,url,form_data,op) {
    console.log(form_data);
//    $(btn).click(function(){
        postLoad(url,form_data,op);
        return false;
//    });
};


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add-acct").on("click",function(){
        var fn=getVal('#fname');
        var dat = {'call':1,'fname':fn};
        reguser('#add-acct','ctrl_register/AJAXreguser',dat,'#acct-detail');
        return false;
    });
});
​
```

Comment: Added the from html for reference. I also tried above but it didn't work.

Comment: class="span8 input-small"id="fname" add a space before the id :)

Comment: Your explanation made sense why I can't get the values I want. So I really have to declare my array inside the click function. I guess I can't DRY this one. Thanks.